# Memory-efficient IList<T> implementation

Tags: c#, .net, list, sockets, collections

I need a collection type for received bytes in my socket application (which deals with ~5k of concurrent connections).

I tried using a `List<byte>` but since it has one internal array and I receive lots of data, it can cause `OutOfMemoryException`s.

So I need a collection that,

- Keeps the data in smaller blocks; like an [Unrolled Linked List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unrolled_linked_list).
- Provides fast lookup (Preferably an `IList<T>`) because I look for a delimiter that marks the end of the message after each receive operation.

What I use right now is `Stream`. I supply a `MemoryStream` for the operations that don't involve too much data and supply a `FileStream` of a temporary file for the operations that involve serious amounts of data.

`MemoryStream` is no different than a `List<T>`, though and I prefer not to use files as buffers.

So...
What collection or approach do you recommend?

Comment: do you slowly dequeue the buffered data from the other end?

Comment: @Marc: No, I don't process the data until I fully assemble a PDU.

Comment: Instead of using a single temporary file for storing the data, you could store the various chunks of data (the ones that have a delimiter) in different files. This could help you to achieve fast retrieving.

Comment: @AS-CII: True, but I don't think I even need to create a file for this becuase I know I'm not out of memory but I'm out of _sequential memory_. My goal here is not to create a file at all and use the memory more efficiently, instead.

Comment: If you need a "Unrolled Linked List", simply take a `LinkedList<byte[]>`, where you instantiate each byte[] with the same size (e.g. `myList.Add(new byte[100]);`).

Comment: @Oliver: I... I even tried to implement one [myself](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/17670/17039) before but using `LinkedList<byte[]>` never occurred to me. :) Thank you.

Comment: I'd rather use `List<byte[]>` with elements that are 1 MiB in size.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using inappropriate architecture for a network application. You should buffer only those data which is required. Here you are using a list to buffer the data until the required amount of data is received.

I would recommend that you should check for delimiter on each receipt of data in the data itself and if it is there, you should push in only the data till you encounter the delimiter. Once the data is ready, you should fetch it out from list and use it and dispose off the list. Adding up everything to the list is not a good approach and will surely consume a lot of memory.

Ideally, you should have a protocol which always inform you before you actually receive the data about the length of data you are going to receive. This way, you can be sure that required data has been received and you should not rely on the delimiter.

Comment: The last part of the answer is useless in my opinion: he says he already knows whether the data is large or small.

Comment: not at all, it depends on how you want to transmit the data. There are many things to be considered, e.g. MTU of network to efficiently transfer the data - so protocol is highly recommended thing.

Comment: The clients are devices that send the data they read from another device as chunks of 300 bytes. So they don't know the length either. (though I know it's maximum size depending on the request I made) which force me to use delimiters instead of length-prefixing. And I already push only the data I need, the problem here is that data can be big.

Comment: In that case, you can also write it to temporary files. Though it is not an efficient technique but when you already know the size of data you are going to receive, it can be highly efficient.

Answer (score 0):

A possible quick and dirty solution:

At the start of the program, allocate a buffer large enough for the largest amount of data you will receive. Use a separate 'count' field to keep track of how much data is currently in use.

(I don't really like this solution; I'd use files or find some way of working with the data in blocks, but it might work for you).

Comment: Wouldn't work since there are ~5k of concurrent connections. I should have mentioned that in the question though, sorry.

Comment: @ŞafakGür Yes you should add that to the question.